# Transition stops to work when I add @keyframes

Tags: css, animation, transform, transition

Scale transform on hover stops to work when I add @keyframes. Both work fine separately, but the following code allows object only to constantly rotating.

```
.rotating {
  animation: rotation 40s infinite linear;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.rotating:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hover and animation do not work together on one object. But you can nest it.

```css
.rotating {
  animation: rotation 40s infinite linear;
  transition: transform 1s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.ontop {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.ontop:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rotating">
     <div class="ontop">rot</div>
</div>
```